# Replace imported list of constants with another list in Python

Tags: python, python-import

My GUI application has two radiobuttons for changing the displayed language. The words are assigned to the constants text1, text2, an so on, in two files:
    file_en.py:

```
text1 = 'Hello'  
text2 = 'Goodbye'  
...
```

file_fr.py:

```
text1 = 'Bonjour'  
text2 = 'Au revoir'  
...
```

On start, the main module imports file_en or file_fr and everything is fine. Now, when the user changes the language - can I immediately replace one imported constants assignment with another?

Comment: please provide us minimal example of usage

Comment: you probably should not store configurations in code, use `json`/`yaml`/`ini` files instead

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, but I think I found a workaround for that. How about you have a function (`loadLang()` or something) that will change the language each time it is called, reading 2 different text files.

```
text1=''
text2='' 
activeLang = 'en' #current language

def loadLang(lang):
    global text1
    global text2
    global activeLang
    if activeLang != lang: #check if current language is 
already what user wants
        file=open("file_" + lang + ".txt", "r") #open file 
       #assuming contents are same as your post without  spaces
        text1=file.readline().rstrip()
        text2=file.readline(2).rstrip() #read line and remove 
\n
       return

#main code
#idk how you're doing it so:
def onClick():
global text1
global text2
       if 'fr' in button.text:
           loadLang('fr')
button1.text = text1
button2.text = text2
```

## Updated solution

You should try this instead, it's must more simple and efficient.

```
import file_en
import file_fr
text1=""
text2=""
activeLang = 'en'#current language
def onClick():
    global text1
    global text2
    global activeLang
    if activeLang == 'en':
        text1 = file_fr.text1
        text2 = file_fr.text2
    elif activeLang == 'fr': #check lang
        text1 = file_en.text1
        text2 = file_en.text2
     else:
        # Error handling goes here
```